# How to remove VTK completely from Ubuntu/*nux?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, vtk

How to remove VTK completely?

I built vtk-6 from the source and installed it to the system using sudo and later I don't want it and but not knowing how to delete them. I tried to manually delete them, but it seems VTK-6.0 and cmake are connected everywhere. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.apart from deleting the usual files for cmake you will have to delete the "../cmake/vtk-6.0/" folder which contains the cmake modules folder

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for uninstalling programs (in addition to VTK). Usually, if make is used, a `make uninstall` should work fine, if not you can **manually** remove the files or use a tool named **checkinstall**.

> ### *** MANUALLY ***

(This worked for me)

**Step 1**
First go to the directory you've build and installed VTK from (probably a 'build' directory).

> **Note:** If you don't have a Makefile and you've changed things you might
> want to replicate the build process using cmake **exactly as before**. This will
> output a new Makefile which will be used to overwrite your existing installation.

**Step 2**
Run the Makefile and install using the following commands: (from the build folder)

run `make` then `touch uninstall.sh && chmod 775 uninstall.sh && echo '#!/bin/bash -v' > uninstall.sh && sudo make install >> uninstall.sh`

**Step 3**
This will create a shell file (for later use) and inputs the install output into the file. Be patient and wait for it to complete. Check the uninstall.sh file by opening it if it contains the installation output. You can now either manually remove the installed files line by line using the filepaths or execute the shell file instead (continue to step 4)

**Step 4**

> **You can remove these lines:**
>
> > [  0%] Built target VTKData
> >
> > [  1%] Built target vtksys
> >
> > [  1%] Built
> >
> > target vtkWrappingTools
> >
> > [  1%] Built target vtkWrapHierarchy ......
> >
> > ...... Install the project...
> >
> > -- Install configuration: "Release"
>
> **You will probably be left with:**
>
> > #!/bin/bash -v
> >
> > -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/VTKConfig.cmake
> >
> > -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/...
> >
> > -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/...

**Step 5**
Now replace '*-- Up-to-date:*' with '*sudo rm*'. (Without the single quotes)

> **Result:**
>
> > #!/bin/bash -v
> >
> > sudo rm /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/VTKConfig.cmake
> >
> > sudo rm /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/...
> >
> > sudo rm /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-8.2/...

**Step 6**
Execute:
`./uninstall.sh`

**Step 7**
There might be vtk folders skipped during the process. Manually remove the leftovers ('/usr/include/vtk-..', '/usr/local/vtk-..', '/usr/local/include/vtk-..')

> ### *** USING CHECKINSTALL ***

I tried this solution from [here](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Uninstall-VTK-help-td5736520.html) but it did not work for me:

> I am using Ubuntu, so there might be a slightly difference from Mint.
> I would do the following:
>
> 1. install checkinstall, it should be available on Mint
> 2. go to VTK-5.10.1 build folder (where you build VTK and run make install from), and run checkinstall (or sudo checkinstall),
>    checkintsall will reinstall (overwrite) VTK-5.10.1 again, meanwhile,
>    it will track what is installed and will also build a installation
>    package (you can give the installation package a name).
> 3. I am 99% sure that at this point, VTK-5.10.1 should be listed in you package manager (eg, Synaptic package manager) but with the name
>    you specified in step 2(if you didn't specify a name for installation
>    package, I think the default name is 'build', maybe followed by year,
>    date and time); if it falls in the 1% and it's not listed in the
>    package manager, install the installation package;
> 4. now you can uninstall it with package manager
>
> I am sure there is a better way, but the above worked for me when I
> was trying to uninstall some other package I build from source...
>
> good luck
>
> Chen